# how to ignore tilde accent in search filter js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, search, filter

When I look in the search engine for a word with an accent, for example: Débora, Lázaro, Ángela, Álvaro, Arquímedes, etc. does not find the result.

Without accents or with upper or lower case, the search engine works excellent.

Someone who can help me, I'm still a beginner in programming.

This is my complete code

```js
const deepMerge = (...objects) => {
  const isObject = (obj) => obj && typeof obj === "object";
  return objects.reduce((prev, obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
      const pVal = prev[key];
      const oVal = obj[key];
      if (Array.isArray(pVal) && Array.isArray(oVal)) {
        prev[key] = pVal.concat(...oVal);
      } else if (isObject(pVal) && isObject(oVal)) {
        prev[key] = deepMerge(pVal, oVal);
      } else {
        prev[key] = oVal;
      }
    });
    return prev;
  }, {});
};

const DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
  classNames: {
    wrapperEl: "cselect",
    selectEl: "cselect__select",
    renderedEl: "cselect__rendered",
    renderedTextEl: "cselect__rendered-text",
    searchEl: "cselect__search",
    optionsEl: "cselect__options",
    optionEl: "cselect__option",
    init: "js-init-cselect",
    open: "is-open",
    onTop: "is-on-top",
    selected: "is-selected",
    hidden: "is-hidden"
  },
  minimumOptionsForSearch: 10,
  onOpen: null,
  onClose: null,
  onToggle: null
};

class CSelect {
  // Elements
  #wrapperEl;
  #renderedEl;
  #renderedTextEl;
  #searchEl;
  #optionsEl;
  #optionEls;
  // Functions
  #handleSearch;
  #optionElClick;
  #clickOutside;
  #escPress;

  constructor(selectEl, options = {}) {
    // Handle arguments
    this.selectEl = selectEl;
    this.options = deepMerge(DEFAULT_OPTIONS, options);
    // Bind 'this'
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.#handleSearch = this.#handleSearchFn.bind(this);
    this.#optionElClick = this.#optionElClickFn.bind(this);
    this.#clickOutside = this.#clickOutsideFn.bind(this);
    this.#escPress = this.#escPressFn.bind(this);
    // Functions
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    // Check if already init
    if (this.selectEl.classList.contains(this.options.classNames.init)) {
      console.error(`CSelect already initialized. ID: ${this.selectEl.id}`);
      return;
    }
    // Handle select element
    this.selectEl.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
    this.selectEl.classList.add(this.options.classNames.selectEl);
    // Functions
    this.#generateHTML();
    this.#addEvents();
    // Add initialization
    this.selectEl.classList.add(this.options.classNames.init);
  }

  #generateHTML() {
    // Generate wrapper
    const wrapperHTML = /* HTML */ `
      <div class="${this.options.classNames.wrapperEl}"></div>
    `;
    this.selectEl.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", wrapperHTML);
    this.#wrapperEl = this.selectEl.previousElementSibling;
    this.#wrapperEl.appendChild(this.selectEl);
    // Generate rendered
    const selectedOption = this.selectEl.options[this.selectEl.selectedIndex];
    const selectedOptionText = selectedOption.textContent;
    this.#renderedEl = document.createElement("button");
    this.#renderedEl.type = "button";
    this.#renderedEl.className = this.options.classNames.renderedEl;
    this.#wrapperEl.appendChild(this.#renderedEl);
    this.#renderedTextEl = document.createElement("span");
    this.#renderedTextEl.className = this.options.classNames.renderedTextEl;
    this.#renderedTextEl.textContent = selectedOptionText;
    this.#renderedEl.appendChild(this.#renderedTextEl);
    // Generate options wrapper
    this.#optionsEl = document.createElement("div");
    this.#optionsEl.className = this.options.classNames.optionsEl;
    this.#wrapperEl.appendChild(this.#optionsEl);
    // Generate search
    if (
      [...this.selectEl.options].length >= this.options.minimumOptionsForSearch
    ) {
      this.#searchEl = document.createElement("input");
      this.#searchEl.type = "text";
      this.#searchEl.className = this.options.classNames.searchEl;
      this.#optionsEl.appendChild(this.#searchEl);
    }
    // Generate each option
    const selectOptions = [...this.selectEl.options];
    this.#optionEls = [];
    for (const option of selectOptions) {
      if (option.disabled) {
        continue;
      }
      const newOption = document.createElement("button");
      newOption.type = "button";
      newOption.className = this.options.classNames.optionEl;
      newOption.textContent = option.textContent;
      newOption.setAttribute("data-value", option.value);
      if (option.selected) {
        newOption.classList.add(this.options.classNames.selected);
      }
      this.#optionsEl.appendChild(newOption);
      this.#optionEls.push(newOption);
    }
  }

  open(callback) {
    this.#wrapperEl.classList.add(this.options.classNames.open);
    // Handle optionsEl position
    this.#handleOptionsElPosition();
    // Handle search
    if (this.#searchEl !== null) {
      this.#resetSearch();
      this.#searchEl.focus();
    }
    // Handle callback functions
    if (typeof this.options.onOpen === "function") {
      this.options.onOpen(this);
    }
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
      callback(this);
    }
  }

  close(callback) {
    this.#wrapperEl.classList.remove(this.options.classNames.open);
    // Handle callback functions
    if (typeof this.options.onClose === "function") {
      this.options.onClose(this);
    }
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
      callback(this);
    }
  }

  toggle(callback) {
    if (!this.#wrapperEl.classList.contains(this.options.classNames.open)) {
      this.open();
    } else {
      this.close();
    }
    // Handle callback functions
    if (typeof this.options.onToggle === "function") {
      this.options.onToggle(this);
    }
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
      callback(this);
    }
  }

  #handleOptionsElPosition() {
    this.#optionsEl.classList.remove(this.options.classNames.onTop);
    const boundingRect = this.#optionsEl.getBoundingClientRect();
    const isOutTop = boundingRect.top < 0;
    const isOutBottom =
      boundingRect.bottom >
      (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    if (isOutBottom) {
      this.#optionsEl.classList.add(this.options.classNames.onTop);
    }
    if (isOutTop) {
      this.#optionsEl.classList.remove(this.options.classNames.onTop);
    }
  }

  #resetSearch() {
    this.#searchEl.value = "";
    for (const optionEl of this.#optionEls) {
      optionEl.classList.remove(this.options.classNames.hidden);
    }
  }

  #handleSearchFn() {
    for (const optionEl of this.#optionEls) {
      if (
        optionEl.textContent
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(this.#searchEl.value.toLowerCase()) > -1
      ) {
        optionEl.classList.remove(this.options.classNames.hidden);
      } else {
        optionEl.classList.add(this.options.classNames.hidden);
      }
    }
  }

  #optionElClickFn(event) {
    // Close the select
    this.close();
    // Cache the target
    const target = event.target;
    // Check if click selected option
    if (this.selectEl.value === target.dataset.value) {
      return;
    }
    // Handle rendered text
    this.#renderedTextEl.textContent = target.textContent;
    // Handle select element change
    this.selectEl.value = target.dataset.value;
    const triggerEvent = new Event("change");
    this.selectEl.dispatchEvent(triggerEvent);
    // Highlight selected
    for (const optionEl of this.#optionEls) {
      optionEl.classList.remove(this.options.classNames.selected);
    }
    target.classList.add(this.options.classNames.selected);
  }

  #clickOutsideFn(event) {
    const isOutside =
      event.target.closest(`.${this.options.classNames.wrapperEl}`) !==
      this.#wrapperEl;
    const isOpen = this.#wrapperEl.classList.contains(
      this.options.classNames.open
    );
    if (isOutside && isOpen) {
      this.close();
    }
  }

  #escPressFn(event) {
    const isEsc = event.keyCode === 27;
    const isOpen = this.#wrapperEl.classList.contains(
      this.options.classNames.open
    );
    if (isEsc && isOpen) {
      this.close();
    }
  }

  #addEvents() {
    this.#renderedEl.addEventListener("click", this.toggle);
    if (this.#searchEl !== null) {
      this.#searchEl.addEventListener("input", this.#handleSearch);
    }
    for (const optionEl of this.#optionEls) {
      optionEl.addEventListener("click", this.#optionElClick);
    }
    document.addEventListener("click", this.#clickOutside);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", this.#escPress);
  }

  destroy() {
    // Check if already init
    if (!this.selectEl.classList.contains(this.options.classNames.init)) {
      console.error(`CSelect not initialized. ID: ${this.selectEl.id}`);
      return;
    }
    // Remove Events
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.#clickOutside);
    document.removeEventListener("keyup", this.#escPress);
    // Unwrap
    this.#wrapperEl.replaceWith(this.selectEl);
    // Clear select element
    this.selectEl.removeAttribute("tabindex");
    this.selectEl.classList.remove(this.options.classNames.selectEl);
    this.selectEl.classList.remove(this.options.classNames.init);
  }
}

// ***

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  window["selectObj"] = {};
  const selectEls = [...document.querySelectorAll(".js-select")];
  for (const selectEl of selectEls) {
    window["selectObj"][selectEl.id] = new CSelect(selectEl, {
      minimumOptionsForSearch: 0
      // onClose: (cselectObj) => {
      //   console.log(cselectObj)
      // },
    });
  }
  // window['selectObj']['select1'].open((cselectObj) => {
  //   console.log(cselectObj)
  // })
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px 150px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* *** */

.cselect {
  position: relative;
}
.cselect,
.cselect *,
.cselect *:before,
.cselect *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cselect__select {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.cselect__rendered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  width: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #333;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cselect__rendered:after {
  content: "▾";
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
}
.cselect.is-open .cselect__rendered:after {
  content: "▴";
}
.cselect__rendered-text {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cselect__options {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 6px 0;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 264px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transform: translateY(-6px) scale(0.98);
  transform-origin: center top;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition-property: transform, visibility, opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 999;
}
.cselect__options::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
}
.cselect__options::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.cselect__options::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #555;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.cselect__options::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #777;
}
.cselect__options.is-on-top {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 100%;
}
.cselect.is-open .cselect__options {
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
.cselect__search {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  width: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.cselect__option {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cselect__option:hover {
  background: #555;
}
.cselect__option.is-selected {
  color: #999;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: default;
}
.cselect__option.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="./" method="get">
  <button type="submit">GET</button>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <div style="max-width: 256px;">
    <select name="select1" id="select1" class="js-select" required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
      <option value="bunny">Perú</option>
      <option value="kitten">Luís</option>
      <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: great - 500 lines - you ask about `~` and it doesn't even appear in your code ... how about you add just enough code to the question to explain what it is you are failing with!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your function **handleSearchFn** to convert characters to the base ones (you can just replace yours with next one):

```
#handleSearchFn() {
  const searchPhrase = this.#searchEl.value.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase();

  for (const optionEl of this.#optionEls) {
    if (optionEl.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchPhrase) > -1) {
      optionEl.classList.remove(this.options.classNames.hidden);
    } else {
      optionEl.classList.add(this.options.classNames.hidden);
    }
  }
}
```